# Upload file using Selenium webdriver. Is there any crossbrowser solution?

Tags: python, selenium, upload

Hi I am trying to figure out how to upload image by Selenium webdriver in python. Here is my code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("fileUpload")
element.send_keys("C:\myfile.jpg")
```

It works well in Chrome, but not in other browsers. The problem is that it either opens OS native file browser or do nothing.

Is there any solution that works in all browsers? (I need Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge)

Comment: Not a solution, but you should use `"C:\\myfile.jpg"`.. Now the backslash is escaping (or use a proper operating system).

Comment: Yeah... I know.

Comment: if replace \ to / should be work 